# Batch file if statements are skipped over

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, error-handling

When executing a portion of my script, it hangs on a set of if statements rather than running the output command.

```
:errorcheck
echo this is the error test, please verify your wireless profiles are listed below.
netsh wlan show profiles
set /p cog="did your profiles show up properly? (Y/N)"
if %cog%=="Y" goto ending
if %cog%=="N" goto retry
echo an error occured, please retry
goto errorcheck
:retry
```

it gets stuck in the loop and just goes back to `:errorcheck`
I already verified the set statement works by using `echo %cog%`, but I cant narrow it down.

Comment: There is no `:ending` location to go to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the environment variables in your IF (or remove the quotes in your test)

```
if "%cog%"=="Y" goto ending
if %cog%==N goto retry
```

otherwise it evaluates to if Y=="Y" which is not true

Also, you may want to add checks for both upper and lowercase versions of Y and N, since it will do a case-sensitive comparison

Comment: Well now the Y statement works, but the N statement force closes the script, thanks for the troubleshooting!

Comment: -@OP: you need to similarly treat the `N` processing - `if "%cog%"=="N" goto retry`. @chrisriccio - Since the user-input may contain *nothing* or *spaces*, using an if-comparison on unquoted strings would generate a syntax-error.

Comment: `if` has a `/i` switch, which could be helpful.

Comment: @magoo I did indeed do that, and It was an error with the If exist statement I had in :retry

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the double quote marks around Y and N in your If statements.  You may also want to change the upper case Y and N to lower or duplicate the lines and check for both cases.

This code worked for me:

```
:errorcheck
echo this is the error test, please verify your wireless profiles are listed below.
netsh wlan show profiles
set /p cog="did your profiles show up properly? (Y/N)"
echo reply is  %cog%
if %cog%==y goto ending
if %cog%==n goto retry
echo an error occured, please retry
goto errorcheck
:retry
goto errorcheck
:ending
```

Comment: Yep I did solve the issue but now whenever I am choosing option N it closes, time to troubleshoot.